# Javascript Event Delegtion -- Adding a timepicker to a popup form

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-delegation

I am attempting to create a [timepicker](http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/) inside of a [popup form](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form).  I am struggling with event delegation -- I am capable of getting the timepicker to work outside of the form, but not inside.

My current code, which does not have the timepicker popup:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#timepick').timepicker({
     showPeriod: true,
     showLeadingZero: true
   });
 });

$(function() {
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Add Time": function() {
                    $( "#time-table tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + time.value + "</td>" + 
                    "</tr>" ); 
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
    });

    $("#add-time").button().click(function() {
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
    });
});
```

This does not work inside of the popup box, only for #timepick outside of it.  I know I somehow need to utilize the .on() jquery function.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#timepick').on("click", function(){
                timepicker({
                showPeriod: true,
                showLeadingZero: true
            });
        });
```

Did not work either.

A pastebin of the current tryout:

http://pastebin.com/gta7TD47

EDIT:

So this MOSTLY works:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#dialog-form').on('click','#time',function() {
            $('#time').timepicker({
                showPeriod: true,
                showLeadingZero: true
            });
          });
        });
```

The only problem is, it currently requires you to click on the box, which then adds the event handler, and then click off and click back on -- so it requires a click before working.  How do I get it to fire immediately? Somehow using .trigger()?

Comment: I've updated my answer to use the `timepicker` method as the actual event handler. I haven't tested it, though. Perhaps you could set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so ppl can work on your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not delegating anything. You're merely binding the event directly on the timepick element. 
If you want to delegate an event, you'll need an aditional selector:

```
$('body').on('click','.allElementsYouNeedSelector',function(){});
```

The code above will apply the anonymous callback function as an event handler for *all* click events that are triggered on *any* element that has the `allElementsYouNeedSelector` class, *anywhere* in the `$('body')` tag.
So if you want to delegate from, say your `dialog-form` element:

```
$('#dialog-form').on('click','*',function()
{//will be called when any child of the #dialog-form is clicked
});
```

Mind you, if you use the `on` method like this, it's translated to [the `delegate` method](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) internally.

*Update:*
In light of your update, I must say: it makes no sense at all to delegate an event for an element that has a unique ID. Perhaps you could try this:

```
$('#time').on('click',{showPeriod: true,showLeadingZero: true},timepicker);
```

This binds a click listener to the `#time` element, and applies the `timepicker` method as an *event handler*, passing the object literal `{showPeriod: true,showLeadingZero: true}` as an argument, just like you're doing. Of course, you can do the same thing using delegation:

```
$('#dialog-form').on('click','*',function()
{//regardles of which child was clicked, apply the timepicker method to #time
    $.timepicker.apply($('#time'),[{showPeriod: true,showLeadingZero: true}]);
});
```

As ever, to avoid having to scan the DOM on each call, you can add a closure

```
$('#dialog-form').on('click','*',(function(time)
{
    return function()
    {
        time = time || $('#time');//in case $('#time') didn't exist when function was created
        $.timepicker.apply(time,[{showPeriod: true,showLeadingZero: true}]);
    };
}($('#time')));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({

            autoOpen: false,

            height: 300,

            width: 350,

            modal: true,

            buttons: {

                "Add Time": function() {

                        $( "#time-table tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +

                            "<td>" + time.value + "</td>" + 

                        "</tr>" ); 

                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                },

                Cancel: function() {

                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                }

            }

        });



        $("#add-time").click(function() { //don't use buttun() here

                $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );

        });




         $('#time').timepicker({ //use the correct id attr of text field
                });

});//end of document
```

/////Html part/////

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">

    <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>



    <form>

    <fieldset>

        <label for="time">Time</label>

        <input type="text" id="time" name="time" style="width: 70px;" id="timepick" value="01:30 PM" />

    </fieldset>

    </form>

</div>


 <button id="add-time">Add time</button>
```

hope this helps